# Best way to store large data set using R from Twitter?

Tags: r, dataset

I am working on a project that aims to retrieve a large data-set (i.e., tweet data which is a couple of days old) from Twitter using the twitteR library on R.  have difficulty storing tweets because my machine has only 8 GB of memory. It ran out of memory even before I set it to retrieve for one day. Is there a way where I can store the tweets straight to my disk without storing into RAM? I am not using the streaming API as I need to get old tweets.

Comment: Why don't you use Python or just command line tools to retrieve Twitter data, save it into chunks (even `gzipped`), and then get back to R for analysis?

Comment: Can python retrieve old tweets using the method you mentioned?

Comment: It can, but you'll need to buy the API access from Twitter or another seller of Twitter history.

Answer (score 5):

Find a way to make your program write to disk periodically. Keep count of the number of tweets you grab and save after that number is high. I don't write R but psuedocode might look like:

`$tweets = get_tweets();
$count = 0;
$tweet_array = array();
for each ($tweets as $tweet) {
  $tweet_array += $tweet;
  $count++;
  if ($count > 10000) {
    append_to_file($tweet_array, 'file_name.txt');
    clear_array($tweet_array);
  }
}`

Comment: yes it might be possible in programming, but for R, the way it process data  is quite differently. I am using the library twitteR from R and the min it an retrieve is one day. I am not sure how am I going to continue from the point I stop tweet if I ran the searchTweets func again.

Comment: Wish I knew more about R to help you out. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

I worked on a Twitter data project last Fall wherein we used Java libraries to pull in tweet data from the streaming and the rest API's. We used [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) (an unofficial Java library) for the  [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/documentation).

The tweet data was fetched and directly written onto text files on our hard drives. Yes, we did increase the memory and heap. I believe R studio will have a similar option. An alternative would be to pull in lesser amounts of tweet data with more number of repetitions.